# Combine data from RTK query with data saved on store

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In our application we have migrated to RTK query for fetching data. While the app becomes more complicated we are having different use cases that we're not completely sure how to tackle them..

In one of our api slices we have an `endpoint` called `getPosts` (not really but for the sake of the example). Something like this:

```js
    .injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (build) => ({
      getPosts: build.query<
        IAPIResponse<IPost[]>
      >({
        query: () => {
          const body = {
              ...
          };
          return {
            method: 'POST',
            url: `${baseUrl}/search`,
            body: {...body, pagination: {perPage: -1}},
          };
        },
      }),
    }),
```

After we fetch this list, we want to initialized all kind of metadata on each fetched post, for example `isFocused`. `isFocused` can be modified by the UI and has no persistance on the server.

So I'm thinking of 2 solutions for this situation:

1. Implement `transformResponse` on this endpoint and add the initial metadata mentioned above. The **bad thing** here is that I won't be able to change the state of those properties since they will be stored in the api slice. Something like this:

```js
        transformResponse: ({posts}) => {
          return posts.map(post => {...post, isFocused: false});
        },
```

2. Save the metadata on a regular redux slice as a map where the key is the `postId` and value is the `metadata` and in order to get the posts with the metadata included I will need to do a computed selector with both fetched data and stored data. The **good thing** is that I can change the metadata by firing some action. The selector would look something like this:

```js
export const selectPosts = createSelector(
  [api.endpoints.getPosts.select(), getMetadaPosts],
  (posts, metadaMap) => {
    return posts.map((post) => {
      return {
        ...post,
        metadata: metadaMap[post.id],
      };
    });
  },
);
```

What would be the right way to go? Is there any other design for this?

Comment: In a way that doesn't solicit opinions, define very carefully what "right way" means

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a Redux state slice for the posts state that contains the `isFocused` property. You can create other actions that operates over the posts state.

Basic Example:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import api from '../path/to/apiSlice';

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
};

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    togglePostFocus: (state, action) => {
      const post = state.posts.find(
        post => post.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (post) {
        post.isFocused = !post.isFocused;
      }
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    // Populate posts state when the getPosts endpoint is fulfilled
    builder.addMatcher(
      api.endpoints.getPosts.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.posts = action.payload.map((post) => ({
          { ...post, isFocused: false }
        }));
      }
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: This could be a problem if I decide to use invalidation on this list, right? Invalidating this list will make this matcher run again and therefore isFocused will be false for everyone again.

Comment: @AmirBaum Sure, this is just a basic example. If that query endpoint is re-fulfilled and you want to keep the existing state you'll need to merge new entries into the state instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can recommend doing this way:

```
export const useGetPosts = (args:MyQueryArgs) => {

const someStuffFromStore = useAppSelector(…);

return useGetPostsQuery(args, { 
  transfomrmResponse: ({ data }) => ({/* My additional logic here */}),
});
```

That way you can get quite flexible hook, that is easier to setup and maintain then using redux core approach..